# How to Fetch Data and then Delete it from database using Spring Webflux?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, functional-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

Delete Operation is not working. How can i fetch data and then delete it in a functional way? The code successfully run but it is not deleting data in database.

## Controller Class

```
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteUserById/{userId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return userService.deleteUserById(userId);
    }
```

## UserService Class

```
    @Override
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> deleteUserById(Long userId) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId)
                .map(user -> {
                    UserDto deletedUser = UserMapper.USER_MAPPER_INSTANCE.toUserDto(user);
                    return "User: " + deletedUser.getUsername() + " deleted!";
                })
                .doOnNext(user -> {
                    userRepository.deleteUserById(userId);
                })
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity
                      .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                      .body("UserId: " +       userId + " Not found"));

   }
```

## Repostiory Interface

```
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE username LIKE $1")
    Mono<User> findByUsername(String username);

    @Query("DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE userid = $1")
    Mono<User> deleteUserById(Long userId);

}
```

## Postgres Table

alertsystem=# select * from tb_user;

userid | username |     name      |           email            | password | ph_number  | date_of_birth | role
--------+----------+---------------+----------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------

```
  5 | am0007   | Ajay Maharjan | ajay007@gmail.com | asdfgh1  | 558955697 | 1999-05-21    | ADMIN
```

## Output

**case: not available userId**

```
UserId: 3 Not found
```

**case: available userId**

```
User: am0007 deleted!
```

I'm trying to delete data in a database in a reactive way. I'm getting expected output but delete operation is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `deleteUserById()` is a reactive operation. It returns `Mono`, but you call it within `doOnNext()` method, so nobody never subsribes to it. Remember the rule: **nothing happens until you subscribe**

The thing is that `doOnNext()` is meant just to put some side effect, for example, to log something.

You should call your delete method inside `flatMap()` operator

```
.flatMap(user -> {
    userRepository.deleteUserById(userId);
})
```

So downstream subsribes to `Mono` returned from that flatMap

Answer (score 0):

---

`deleteUserById()` was returning `mono<Void>` despite declaring `Mono<User>`. So what I did was, I changed it into `Mono<Void>` and then added `.thenReturn(user)` which returned `Mono<User>` from the flatMap.

```
return userRepository.findById(userId)
            .flatMap(user -> userRepository.deleteUserById(userId).thenReturn(user))
            .map(user -> {
                log.info("Deleted User: {}", user);
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("User: " + user.getUsername() + " deleted!");
            })
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("UserId: " + userId + " Not found"));
```